# Maximum subtree sum

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I have written a code for the following problem:

> You are given an arbitrary binary tree consisting of N nodes, your task is to find maximum subtree sum.

I just want to know why is the code wrong:

```
pair<long long,long long> subTree(BinaryTreeNode<int> *root){

    if(root == NULL ){
        pair<int,int> p = make_pair(0,0);
        return p;
    }

    pair<long long,long long> left = subTree(root->left);
    pair<long long,long long> right = subTree(root->right);

    int leftsum = left.first;
    int rightsum = right.first;
    int totalsum = leftsum+rightsum+root->data;
    int maxi = max(totalsum,max(leftsum,rightsum));
    
    pair<long long,long long> ans = make_pair(totalsum,maxi);

    return ans;
    
}

long long maxSubtreeSum(BinaryTreeNode<int> *root){
    pair<long long,long long> p = subTree(root);
    return p.second;
}
```

Comment: I would do a bottom-up traversal of the tree. At each node, calculate two (3) values and return them: the sum of the subtree at that node; and maximum sum found in that subtree; and the node identity of the maximum sum node in that subtree.

Comment: For a leaf node (node with no children), the three values are: the node's own value; the node's own value, and the node itself.   I.e. the sum is that of the node itself, and it is also the largest sum found so far, and the identity of the largest sum node is that node itself.

Comment: For a non-leaf node, you have to integrate the results from the child(ren) and the current node. If there are two children, you get their three values. You add the first values, plus the node's own value, to get the subtree sum here. Then you compare which of the three sums is the largest: the left child's maximum, rght child's maximum or this node's value.  From that you calculate the second and third value to return.   There are also simple cases for when there is only one child.

Comment: How have you come to the understanding that the "code is wrong"? Did you get an error message? An infinite recursion? A wrong output? For which input?

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `maxSubtreeSum` (which is `long long`) seems to suggest that the expected sum may exceed the range of an `int`.

In case your implementation is called with a tree whose max sum will indeed exceed the `int` range, you'll at some point get a wrong result in this statement:

```
int totalsum = leftsum+rightsum+root->data;
```

To fix this, declare the variables that hold intermediate sums as `long long` instead of `int`. So:

```
long long leftsum = left.first;
long long rightsum = right.first;
long long totalsum = leftsum+rightsum+root->data;
long long maxi = max(totalsum,max(leftsum,rightsum));
```